# Margin Bounds Wider & Taller In PrintDocument.Print() Than In PrintPreviewDialog.ShowDialog()

Tags: vb.net, printing, margin

The display of the `PrintPreviewDialog` is perfect, and if I do `PrintDocument.Print()` and use a virtual printer like PDF995, it's also perfect. However, if I do `PrintDocument.Print()` and select a physical printer (and yes, I've tried multiple printers), then the top left corner of the box is placed correctly, but not the bottom right corner. The bottom right is 5.5mm further to the right (on the paper), and 7 mm further towards the bottom.

I have drawn a visual aid to further clarify what's going on. The red box is is what I expect, and what happens when I use the `PrintPreviewDialg` or print to a virtual printer. The blue box is what happens when I use `PrintDocument.Print()` and select a physical printer.

Does anyone know why this happening, and more importantly what I can do to solve it?

[image: Print vs. Print Preview]

---

#### The code for my Print button...

```
Dim doc As New Printing.PrintDocument
doc.OriginAtMargins = True
doc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Printing.Margins(50, 50, 50, 50)
AddHandler doc.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintPage

Dim printer As New PrintDialog
printer.Document = doc
printer.UseEXDialog = True
If printer.ShowDialog(Me) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    printer.Document.Print()
End If
```

#### The code for my Print Preview button...

```
Dim doc As New Printing.PrintDocument
doc.OriginAtMargins = True
doc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Printing.Margins(50, 50, 50, 50)

AddHandler doc.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintPage

Dim preview As New PrintPreviewDialog
preview.Document = doc
preview.ShowDialog(Me)
```

#### Code for `PrintPage()` routine...

```
Public Sub PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
    Dim Bounds As New Rectangle(e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.X, e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Y, e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height)
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, Bounds)
    e.HasMorePages = False
End Sub
```

---

I have also tried setting `OriginAtMargin` to `False` and using `e.MarginBounds` instead of my `Bounds` `Rectangle`. Both result in exactly the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are using the setting: `e.PageSettings.PrintableArea.X` when drawing your rectangle - this may vary according to whatever printer you are using. You would want to use something like:

```
Dim Bounds As New Rectangle(e.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.left, e.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.top, e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height)
```

Bear in mind that this will likely result in the edge getting cut off in the printer and not printing, unless the PrintableArea setting for the printer is somehow not correct...

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't see how changing the X or Y coordinate is going to fix anything? The top and left sides are fine, it's the right and bottom sides that are incorrect. Also, I do not see a `DefaultPageSettings` object in `e` which is a `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs` object.